# Phonegap CSS :focus and/or :active on button not working

Tags: ios, css, cordova, focus

I use `.btn:focus{}` and in browser works perfectly i tryed also `.btn:active` same, but when i launch phonegap in ios simulator it won't work either :focus and :active, what's up?

html:

`<button type="button">Asd button</div>`

css:

`button:focus,button:active{ background:pink;}`

Comment: How are you trying to focus a non-input element in iOS?  I don't know what would constitute a focussed button in a touch based operating system.

Comment: @Owen'Coves'Jones clicking with mouse on button

Comment: @Owen'Coves'Jones so not possible to test focus and active statuses using simulator? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't test the focus of a button in iOS because you can't focus a button in iOS, it's not like you can tab to it with the keyboard like with a desktop OS, so focus is kinda only really for inputs on touch devices.

As to active, an active state should work, but may be either delayed by waiting to re-render until after the end of touch device, or by an error in your code.  The simulator doesn't always behave exactly like iOS, due to having to translate the actions performed on a desktop device to a touch environment.